# display item in select dropdown

Tags: php, javascript, html, select

I have a simple html dropdown box

```
<select class="dr_down">
<option>item1</option>
<option>item2</option>
<option>item3 etc...</option>
</select>
```

What I need to do is show the selected item when the form is edited instead of it defaulting back to the top of the list.

Comment: what do you mean by "when the form is edited"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some array with values and have selected values you should to use something like this

```
<select>
<?php foreach( $yourData as $id => $name ):?>
  <option <?php echo $id === $yourCurretID ? "selected='selected'" : ''?> ><?php echo $name?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `selected` attribute:

```
<select class="dr_down">
   <option>item1</option>
   <option selected='true'>item2</option>
   <option>item3 etc...</option>
</select>
```

That will select 'item2' by default

Comment: how would I implement this when dragging the selected item from a database in PHP ?

Comment: that depends on how you are populating the list. The basic idea is while you're outputting the options, you would append the `selected` attribute to the item you want to be selected.

Comment: unfortunately the form I have been given is in static html

Answer (score 1):

did you try using attribute `selected='true'`

Answer (score 0):

use `selected` atribute to preselect your option e.g.

```
<option selected="selected">item2</option>
```